# Upsource .jvmoptions and JVM max heap size

Tags: jvm, jetbrains-ide, upsource

I want to change the heap size made available to the multiple Upsource processes (frontend, cassandra, etc) when running it in a docker container.

I'm trying to make the configuration by using the documented [manual approach](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/upsource/tuning-up-a-docker-installation.html#4198a7a8) which is basically to change the 'upsource-frontend.jvmoptions' file content.

Other JVM options, like for example `-XX:ErrorFile` does produce the expected outcome when changing that file, but apparently changing the default value for `-Xmx` **is not** effective.

I'm running `jetbrains/upsource:2018.2.1154`

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Could you provide more information?  I have successfully used changed the Java heap size and it was effective in fixing my problems.   Could tell us what you want to do?

Comment: I want to change the heap size made available to Upsource when running it in a docker container. 
I have changed the 'upsource-frontend.jvmoptions' using the documented manual approach [1]. 

Every JVM configuration I've done seems to work, expect the '-Xmx'.

[1] https://www.jetbrains.com/help/upsource/tuning-up-a-docker-installation.html#4198a7a8

Comment: updated the question to hopefully make it clearer